# Thread Synchronization Issue in java

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, synchronization

I am working on Soap WebServices application using hibernate. In that I am generating orderNumbers for each order. To do so I have following table with two fields

ORDER_SERIES  LAST_ORDER_COUNT

---

ORD 250

To generate ORDER_NO first I get the record from above table and increament LAST_ORDER_COUNT by 1 and append with ORDER_SERIES

so my ORDER_NO would be ORD251

after that I am updating above table with new increamented LAST_ORDER_COUNT

ORDER_SERIES  LAST_ORDER_COUNT

---

ORD     251

I have written one Method to do this operation means get record from table, increament LAST_ORDER_COUNT append both and return order no and update LAST_ORDER_COUNT. I made this method as synchronized.

but in production environment I am getting duplicate ORDER_NOs

my soap webservices are getting Called through android apk.

any idea why ORDER_NO are getting duplicate

Comment: It is because your operation is not atomic. What DBMS are you using. In most of them are built-in methodologies to create unique IDs atomically.

Comment: I am using postgres database

Comment: I found solution for the above issue. We can use "select for update" query while selecting the record. While we select any record using "select for update" then that record is locked until we update it. Means no two threads can get same value from for particular record

Answer (score 0):

Id should be auto increment in the database and it should be a primary/Unique key as well. if you will not do so then in future, you would face such type of issue when you will have more request simultaneously.